# How to include CSS from node_modules in Vite in production?

Tags: css, typescript, npm, vite

I have a typescript web application that includes CSS files from its NPM dependencies in index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/notyf/notyf.min.css" />
```

After I added vite to my project, this works in development mode (`vite`), because it serves the content from my development folder where the path to node_modules exists. However this breaks in production (`vite build`) or preview mode (`vite preview`) where it is served in another folder and the node_modules folder doesn't get included in the output.

My old workflow was to just `npm install` on the web server so it had all it's dependencies in the node_modules folder, but this does not work with an application bundled by Vite.

I consulted the manual including https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css but all the examples in the manual concern people using frameworks and libraries like PostCSS, React, Vue, tailwind, SASS and so on. However I don't use any of those technologies.

How can I get Vite to include CSS files from NPM dependencies in just a simple typescript application consisting of ES6 modules with no frameworks whatsoever?

The manual says something about importing but I don't understand, how and where exactly to import the CSS, in the index.html or in the modules?

Comment: in `main.js` you try doing `import 'notyf/notyf.min.css'`, let me know if that work.

Comment: @syed: Yes, this works! Can you make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `main.js` try the below-given code and this should work.

`import 'notyf/notyf.min.css'`

Comment: You need to be mindful of the file path you're importing your css file into.
i.e: If you're on src/main.js, you need to link it relatively using "../" like (../node_modules/lib/index.css)